# SIGTRAP when freeing first element of a Queue

Tags: c, memory, free

I'm in trouble, everytime my function calls "desenfileirar" I had some breakpoints. Can anyone help me? I need to print a bidimensional array that means the path traveled by an ant. It needs to start at (0,0) and reach to (9,9). That I get success, only using the "handle SIGTRAP nostop" command at debugger. I implemented the BFS algorithm, but I'm unsuccessful at dequeue the elements. It means a memory violation, I believe

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
In ntdll!TpWaitForAlpcCompletion () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
In ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerDivide () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
In ntdll!RtlCopyExtendedContext () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
#10 0x004014cd in desenfileirar (F=0x28fe74) at I:\Exercício-1\Formiga.c:60
I:\Exercício-1\Formiga.c:60:1306:beg:0x4014cd
At I:\Exercício-1\Formiga.c:60
```

---

here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "Fila.h"

struct st_no{
    int linha; //coordinate from array line
    int coluna; //coordinate from array column
    int plinha; //coordinate from the generator of line (father)
    int pcoluna; //coordinate from the generator of column (father)
    FILA *prox;
};

void geraFilhos(FILA **Q, FILA **gerador, short int *matriz[N][N], int *visitados[N][N]);
void print_shortest_path(FILA **F, FILA **src, FILA **dst);

/**=========================== FUNÇÕES DA FILA ===========================**/
bool vazia(FILA **F){
    return *F == NULL;
}

void criar(FILA **F){
    *F = NULL;
}

void enfileirar(FILA **F, int i, int j, int paiI, int paiJ){
    FILA *novo, *P;
    novo = (FILA *)malloc(sizeof(FILA*));
    novo->linha = i;
    novo->coluna = j;
    novo->plinha = paiI;
    novo->pcoluna = paiJ;
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if(*F == NULL)
        *F = novo;
    else{
        P = *F;
        while(P->prox != NULL)
            P = P->prox;
        P->prox = novo;
    }
}

FILA *desenfileirar(FILA **F){
    FILA *P, *ret = (FILA*)malloc(sizeof(FILA));
    if(vazia(F)){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        P = *F;
        ret->linha = P->linha;
        ret->coluna = P->coluna;
        ret->plinha = P->plinha;
        ret->pcoluna = P->pcoluna;
        ret->prox = NULL;
        *F = (*F)->prox;
        free(P); // HERE I HAD THE BREAKPOINTS
    }
    return ret;
}

FILA *buscar(FILA **L, int i,int j){
    FILA *P;

    P = *L;
    while(P != NULL){
        if(P->linha == i && P->coluna == j)
            return P;
        P = P->prox;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void imprimir(FILA **F){
    FILA *P;

    P = *F;
    printf("Fila:\n");
    while(P != NULL){
        printf("(%i,%i)", P->linha, P->coluna);
        printf("(%i,%i)\n\n", P->plinha, P->pcoluna);
        P = P->prox;
    }
}

FILA *atribuicao(FILA **F, int i, int j){
    FILA *aux = (FILA*)malloc(sizeof(FILA));
    aux->linha = i;
    aux->coluna = j;
    aux->prox = NULL;
    *F = aux;
    return *F;
}

/**=========================== FUNÇÕES QUE ACHAM O CAMINHO ===========================**/

void caminhar(short int *matriz[N][N], FILA *inicio,FILA *objetivo){
    FILA *abertos, *x, *fechado;
    int i, j, *visitados[N][N];

    criar(&abertos);
    criar(&fechado);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            visitados[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    inicio->plinha = -1;
    inicio->pcoluna = -1;
    enfileirar(&abertos,inicio->linha,inicio->coluna,inicio->plinha,inicio->pcoluna);
    while(!vazia(&abertos)){
        x = desenfileirar(&abertos);
        enfileirar(&fechado,x->linha,x->coluna,x->plinha,x->pcoluna);
        if(x->linha == objetivo->linha && x->coluna == objetivo->coluna){
            printf("Parou aqui!\n\n\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            geraFilhos(&abertos,&x,matriz,visitados);
            visitados[x->linha][x->coluna] = 1;
        }
    }
    imprimir(&fechado);
    print_shortest_path(&fechado,&inicio,&objetivo);
}

void geraFilhos(FILA **Q, FILA **gerador, short int *matriz[N][N], int *visitado[N][N]){
    FILA *P = *gerador;

    if((P->coluna+1 < N)&&(matriz[P->linha][P->coluna+1] == 0) && (visitado[P->linha][P->coluna+1] == 0)){//direita
        P->plinha = P->linha;
        P->pcoluna = P->coluna;
        P->coluna++;
        enfileirar(Q,P->linha,P->coluna,P->plinha,P->pcoluna);
        P->coluna--;
    }
    if((P->linha+1 < N)&&(matriz[P->linha+1][P->coluna] == 0) && (visitado[P->linha+1][P->coluna] == 0)){//baixo
        P->plinha = P->linha;
        P->pcoluna = P->coluna;
        P->linha++;
        enfileirar(Q,P->linha,P->coluna,P->plinha,P->pcoluna);
        P->linha--;
    }
    if((P->coluna-1 >= 0)&&(matriz[P->linha][P->coluna-1] == 0) && (visitado[P->linha][P->coluna-1] == 0)){//esquerda
        P->plinha = P->linha;
        P->pcoluna = P->coluna;
        P->coluna--;
        enfileirar(Q,P->linha,P->coluna,P->plinha,P->pcoluna);
        P->coluna++;
    }
    if((P->linha-1 >= 0)&&(matriz[P->linha-1][P->coluna] == 0) && (visitado[P->linha-1][P->coluna] == 0)){//cima
        P->plinha = P->linha;
        P->pcoluna = P->coluna;
        P->linha--;
        enfileirar(Q,P->linha,P->coluna,P->plinha,P->pcoluna);
        P->linha++;
    }
}

void print_shortest_path(FILA **F, FILA **src, FILA **dst){
    FILA *P, *Q;
    Q = *F;
    printf("CAMINHO: \n\n\n");

    printf("(%d,%d)\n", (*dst)->linha,(*dst)->coluna);
    while((*dst)->linha != (*src)->linha && (*dst)->coluna != (*src)->coluna){
        P = buscar(&Q,(*dst)->linha,(*dst)->coluna);
        printf("(%d,%d)\n", P->plinha,P->pcoluna);
        (*dst)->linha = P->plinha;
        (*dst)->coluna = P->pcoluna;
    }
    printf("(%d,%d)\n", (*src)->linha,(*src)->coluna);
}

/**=========================== MAIN ===========================**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Fila.h"

/*
 *
 */
 void caminhar(short int *matriz[N][N], FILA *inicio,FILA *objetivo);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
FILE *arq = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    int i, j;
    int tabuleiro[N][N];

    FILA *inicial, *objetivo;

    criar(&inicial);
    criar(&objetivo);

    inicial = atribuicao(&inicial,0,0);
    objetivo = atribuicao(&objetivo,N-1,N-1);

    if(!arq){
        printf("Nao deu pra ler!");
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
                fscanf(arq,"%d",&tabuleiro[i][j]);
            }
        }

        printf("INICIO: (0,0)\n");
        printf("OBJETIVO: (%d,%d)\n\n", N, N);

        caminhar(tabuleiro,inicial,objetivo);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/**=========================== FILA.H ===========================**/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10

typedef struct st_no FILA;

void criar(FILA **F);
void destruir(FILA **F);
bool vazia(FILA **F);
void enfileirar(FILA **F, int i, int j, int paiI, int paiJ);
FILA *desenfileirar(FILA **F);
void imprimir(FILA **F);
FILA *atribuicao(FILA **F, int i, int j);
```

Comment: This, to my knowledge, does absolutely nothing: `if(*F == NULL){
        free(*F);
        *F = NULL;
    }`

Comment: I'm sure about this. I only copied that from my teacher...

Comment: I would kindly mention that to him/her. It only serves to add extra bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to have a [complete, compilable example](http://sscce.org/), because you provide the source for functions named `desenfileirar` and `caminhar`, but you also use functions named `criar`, `enfileirar`, `vazia`, `geraFilhos`, `imprimir`, and `print_shortest_path`, and you use a structure name `FILA` without providing definition. Also, you never show a `malloc()` but you show calls to `free()`.

The `free()` at the beginning of `caminhar()` is inherently pointless (calling `free(NULL)` is guaranteed not to do anything, and explicitly setting `*f = NULL` only if `*f` is already `NULL`? Also, I'm sure you'll agree, not helpful), but harmless.

The immediately glaring problem that I see is that your `ret` is a pointer to a `FILA`, but you are using it without allocating storage for it. This means that when you enter the `desenfileirar()` function, a variable named `ret` is created, with enough storage for a pointer to `FILA`, but with no explicitly assigned value, and you then treat it as a valid pointer, and write through it. (And then you're `return`ing it, too...) This is Undefined Behaviour, several times over, and fortunately for you, you got lucky enough that this time, it failed during testing. There's more than one possible solution for this, but without seeing your entire program, I don't know which one to recommend. (The likeliest solution, nevertheless, is simply to insert a line reading `ret=malloc(sizeof *ret);` right before you start using it.)

```
**UPDATE**
```

Now that you've posted additional code, here's my further analysis. This appears to be several source files, but it clearly still isn't compilable, and is missing `Fila.h`.

In `enfileirar()`, you're using `malloc()` to allocate enough storage for a pointer to `FILA` instead of enough storage for a `FILA`. In `desenfileirar()`, you have a syntax error on the first line, in the call to `malloc()`. Also, you have a memory leak if `*F==NULL`. Don't `malloc()` storage for `ret` until you need it. You also have a random `2` on the `free()` line., and you're forgetting to initialize `ret->prox=NULL`, which will lead to Undefined Behaviour at some random later point. In `atribuicao()`, you're forgetting to initialize `aux->prox=NULL`.

Your problems are almost certainly stemming from the two places where you are forgetting to initialize the `prox` element of a new FILA. This is because memory returned from `malloc()` is not blank, the content is indeterminate. So if you don't set `prox=NULL`, when you walk the list you're going to walk off the end into totally random memory.

Comment: I've posted the full code now! And, thank you very much for any help! In the oldest version of the code, I had the allocation to ret, but for some unknown reason, I taken it off.

Comment: Now, I've been updated the code, with the changes that you mean. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Your `desenfileirar()` function received a pointer to a list. It allocates a new structure, copies the head of the list into the new structure, then repoints the list at the next element, and frees the head. It also has a *memory leak*. Why not save yourself the effort, and eliminate the allocate/copy step? `FILE *desenfileirar(FILA **F) { FILA *P; if (vazia(F)) {return NULL;} else {P=*F; *F=(*F)->prox; return P;}}` (Oh, yes: Where's you sample input data?)

Comment: There. *Much* simpler, and eliminates one potential memory leak. (You still have others, of course...)

Comment: It's a part of evaluation freeing and memory allocation. I need to free the unqueued element. So, I need to copy it to a pointer of type FILA and return this pointer. I know it's a waste of memory, but, I need to do this if I want 100% score.

teste.txt is: 

"0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0"

Note: it's a bidimensional array 5x5

Comment: So, needs change N 5 at "Fila.h"

Comment: Your code above still shows the incorrect malloc() in the `enfileirar()` function. And tell me, since `NULL` is a valid and expected possible return value from the `buscar()` function, how are you handling that? (Hint: you're not.)

Comment: Note: After you fix the `malloc()` in the `enfileirar()` function, fix the mishandling of the return value of your call to `buscar()` in the `print_shortest_path()` function, and fix the three-way type mismatch between how you declare the first argument of the `caminhar()` function, how you declare the variable that gets used as the first argument, and what you're actually passing (hint: all three are wrong), then if you're still having problems (hint: you can't actually pass an array as an argument to a function in C), please provide details of exactly where the problems occur.

Comment: Also: Since this question was specifically about memory access violations in `desenfileirar()`, if those are fixed, please consider accepting the answer, and posting a new question if further issues arise.

Comment: I've fixed the things that you said and the code runs partially. Now, the problem is in print_shortest_path. Here's the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513592/print-shortest-path-using-concepts-of-bfs Many thanks, Elchonon Edelson

Comment: I've fixed the code and here it's, running completely: http://pastebin.com/Lkb4Dh5P